# Validation, repository classes and code structure in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, validation, razor

I already asked a similar question to this but i can't even look the code i write, it looks horrible. There is something wrong.

I'm trying to create a simple web application with Visual Studio, [ASP.Net Web Pages](http://www.asp.net/web-pages) and Entity Framework. People are not familiar with Web Pages, it's basically a development environment like classic ASP and PHP.

I have two tables, one is workers and other one is overhours. I created models for both, they are related so every overhour record has one worker.

Basically i'm using this code:

```
if (IsPost)
{
    try
    {
        Worker curWorker = new Worker();
        try
        {
            curWorker = m.Workers.Find(decimal.Parse(Request.Form["WorkerId"]));
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            errors += "Please select a worker.";
        }

        try
        {
            overhour.OverhourAmount = decimal.Parse(Request.Form["OverhourAmount"]);
            if (overhour.OverhourAmount == 0)
            {
                throw new Exception();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            errors += "Hour field should be numerical and non-zero.";
        }

        overhour.Worker = curWorker;
        overhour.OverhourDate = DateTime.Today;
        curWorker.Overhours.Add(overhour);

        if (errors != "")
        {
            throw new WrongValueException(errors);
        }

        m.SaveChanges();
        Response.Redirect(Page.ParentPage);
    }
    catch (DbEntityValidationException ex)
    {
        errors = kStatic.getValidationErrors(ex.EntityValidationErrors, "<br />");
    }
    catch (WrongValueException ex)
    {
        errors = ex.Message.ToString();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        errors = "Critical error, technical details: " + ex.Message;
    }
}
```

Form has a combobox with all workers named **WorkerId**. It works but i have a few problems.

1. I hate validation method. I need to validate if user has selected a valid worker from the combobox because it has an option named "Select a worker" and it's value is empty string, so i need to check if it's numerical. I can include a [Regex..] code to my model class but it doesn't matter because there will be an error when i try to assign string to decimal field (decimal WorkerId). I can catch the exception but it will be likely a mismatch exception. I need more details.
2. Same thing with OverhourAmount, it should be numerical and non-zero too.
3. I don't like putting this code into the page code itself. I can create a repository class with methods like **r.addOverhour** but people say it's unnecesary. Is it unnecesary for MVC or if you're using Entity Framework, you shouldn't use an extra repository class.
4. I want to check the database for some validation before saving changes. For example, an user (user who has username and password, not worker) shouldn't be able to create a record about a worker if they are not in same building. For example, user A works in building X, and worker H works in building Y, user A shouldn't be able to create any data related to worker H. So i need to check if they work in same building before adding the record. I have BranchId field in both user and worker tables, i can check that easily but where?

Basically i don't know how to structure my code. I think i'm missing something big here because everybody validates their data and filter their inputs.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Decorate your dtos with validation.  Modelbinding will verify your data automatically and if failed will return the property that fails validation and the reason which you can customize.  You business rules need to happen in a logic layer which will basically operate on your data models and return dtos.  Your logic layer will accept dtos and this will provide separation from the data layer from the web API/mvc

Comment: I can't use modelbinding in Web Pages. Do i really have to use MVC for this?